# Accuracy of python decimals

Tags: python-3.x

How do I make the decimal in Python more accurate, so that I can calculate up to

```
0.0000000000001 * 0.0000000000000000001 = ?
```

I need to add decimals like 0.0000000145 and 0.00000000000000012314 and also multiply them and get the exact result. Is there a needed code, or is there a module? Thanks in advance.

I need something that is more accurate than decimal.Decimal.

Comment: "I need something that is more accurate than decimal.Decimal" - if you think that, then you're misunderstanding `decimal.Decimal` and floating point in general.

Comment: Misunderstanding something is a sure fire reason for asking a question @user2357112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting downvoted.

decimal.Decimal represents numbers using floating point in base 10. Since it isn't implemented directly in hardware, you can control the level of precision (which defaults to 28 places):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
0.142857
```

However, you may prefer to use the [mpmath module](http://mpmath.org) instead, which supports arbitrary precision real and complex floating point calculations:

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> print(mp.quad(lambda x: mp.exp(-x**2), [-mp.inf, mp.inf]) ** 2)
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
```

Comment: It's not clear here @UriGranta why you suggest `mpmath` since `decimal` can also adjust the precision. According to [the decimal docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#constants), if I'm understanding it right, the supported `decimal.MAX_PREC` is `999999999999999999`. I think that would be enough for the OP judging from his examples. What's the advantage of `mpmath`?